# Wondering if I can change a cap value in a design

Tags: capacitor, substitution

I am assembling a circuit from the ESP32 reference design.

Looking at value C1 page 18 https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf (10uF) but I don't have any of these on hand, I have 4.7uF and 100uF.

Would either of those sizes be an acceptable substitute?

[image: Reference schematic]

Comment: 1. Be better to post the circuit here. 2. No C1 on page 18 that I could find. (Actually there is no page marked 18)

Comment: You must be referring to page 12 or 13. For the most part you can just double the number of 4.7 uF caps, but I sure hope you have the 100 nF bypass caps or it will not work.

Comment: Are the ones you have ceramic or are they electrolytic type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bulk capacitor for the ESP32 module. Since there is already capacitance on the board itself, that value is less critical. The 0.1uF is far more critical, but can be substituted for a 0.47uF or 0.33uF in a pinch.

I would choose the 4.7uF, but you could always put down two of them instead of 1 and that makes close to 10uF.

100uF would probably work, but the impedance of the capacitor will have somewhat different characteristics from the 10uF and may not be as effective (assuming they did their homework with the reference design).

Answer (score 0):

The 10uF in the circuit is a simple bulk capacitor on the 3.3V power. I don't imagine its value being critical.  Either the 4.7uF or the 100uF should work.